# Sorting a vector in R in a specific order

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I am solving a constrained optimization problem in `R` iteratively where the problem if of the following form:

min f(x)

s.t. g(x) < 0

I am doing the optimization iteratively and so I have a variable called `f` that holds the current value of the function f and vector `g` of 1's and 0's that tells me if the constraint was met for the ith iteration.  To help, here is an example

```
#Imagine there are 6 time points 
f = c(7,10,6,3,-1,-9)  
g = c(1,1,0,1,1,0)
```

And so I want to keep track of the best minimum value found at the ith iteration such that the constraint was satisfied.  Thus I want to be able to calculate a vector like

```
h = c(7,7,7,3,-1,-1)
```

Where `h` records the minimum value found in time such that the constraint was met. Is there an easy way to do this in `R` either in loops or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your `f` and `g`, I would do it like this:

```
cummin(zoo::na.locf(ifelse(g == 1, f, NA)))
# [1]  7  7  7  3 -1 -1
```

Or, perhaps more simply:

```
cummin((ifelse(g == 1, f, Inf)))
# [1]  7  7  7  3 -1 -1
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you so much!